# AJAX Accordion Expand all Panels on page load

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I am using ASP.NET AJAX accordion . http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx .
Is there any way to expand all panels on page load ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you might want collapsible panels: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordion control supports only one active pane at a time. You can have all panes collapsed stage but only once can be active at a time.

For what you need, you can use multiple [collapsible panels](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx).

Alternative can be to use [jquery sliding](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/) which I would prefer. Here's the [quick fiddle that I put up](http://jsfiddle.net/rcgh7/5/) to start you through.

Comment: +1 the sliding technique always seems to perform better than AJAX.

Comment: +1 for the jquery sliding. The fiddle you linked helped me to do exactly what I needed. Thank you!